# How to scrape section of HTML and extract text?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the string `2 and a half stars, 4688 Ratings` in python from the below HTML element.

I used this command and got this set of data. I can't figure out how to extract this portion of data that I need.

Here is the code I ran:

```
print(soup.find_all('div',{'class':'extra-list customer-ratings'})[0])
```

Here is the outcome:

```
<div class="extra-list customer-ratings">
<h4>Customer Ratings</h4>
<div>Current Version:</div>
<div aria-label="2 and a half stars, 4688 Ratings" class="rating" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" role="img" tabindex="-1"><span itemprop="ratingValue" style="display: none;">2.7308</span><div><span class="rating-star"> </span><span class="rating-star"> </span><span class="rating-star half"> </span><span class="rating-star ghost"> </span><span class="rating-star ghost"> </span></div><span class="rating-count" itemprop="reviewCount">4688 Ratings</span>
</div>
<div>All Versions:</div>
<div aria-label="3 and a half stars, 106508 Ratings" class="rating" role="img" tabindex="-1"><div><span class="rating-star"> </span><span class="rating-star"> </span><span class="rating-star"> </span><span class="rating-star half"> </span><span class="rating-star ghost"> </span></div><span class="rating-count">106508 Ratings</span>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't really know where to begin here. I tried slicing, but if I use a new HTML file then the data gets pulled out in the wrong place.

Comment: Welcome to SO - A really good first post so only in addition some info that could be helpful for further once [tour],  [ask] and [mcve] Have a good start.

Comment: I also had problems extracting divs with multiple classes from find_all, I suggest using select 
select('div.extra-list.customer-ratings')[0]. It works well. to get the aria-label you can then use select('div.extra-list.customer-ratings')[0].get('aria-label'). get here is used for the attributes of a tag.

Answer (score 0):

The content you try to print is in the `aria-label` [attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#bs4.Tag.attrs) of an `div` element you have to locate separatly:

```
for element in soup.select('div.extra-list.customer-ratings [itemprop="aggregateRating"]'):
      print(element.get('aria-label'))
```

For convenience I used [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) here to chain what i like to select.

---

You could also go with `find_all()` and selecting more precisely:

```
for element in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'extra-list customer-ratings'}):
      print(element.find('div',{'itemprop':'aggregateRating'}).get('aria-label'))
```

Or in case there is only on element use `find()` instead and select ist directly:

```
soup.find('div',{'itemprop':'aggregateRating'}).get('aria-label')
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: found a way with beautifulsoup directly,

```
print(soup.find('div', {'class': 'rating', 'aria-label': any})['aria-label'])
```

=> 2 and a half stars, 4688 Ratings

- original answer:

if [lxml](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/) is an acceptable dependency, you can do

```
print(lxml.html.fromstring(html).xpath('//div[@class="rating" and @aria-label]/@aria-label')[0])
```

=> 2 and a half stars, 4688 Ratings